# MySQL - INSERT INTO says I have worng syntax with 'to'='$user2'

Tags: php, mysql, chat

```
$time=date("G:i:s j.n.Y");
$wholetime="$time";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rivase_chat_posts SET sender='$user', content='$msg', time='$wholetime', 'to'='$affectuser'");
$msg="";
```

I am doing a private chat thing. That is my code. It results this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''to'='gs'' at line 1
>  ($user="gskartwii", $msg="HI",
>   $affectuser='gs')

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For column names, use backticks rather than single-quotes:

```
`to`='$affectuser'
```

Single quotes are there for strings only. Backticks (normally left of the number 1 on your keyboard) are the things to use for column or table names in mysql.

Edit: As Michael Berkowski correctly points out, the reason you have to do this for the column name is because `to` is a reserved word in mysql - which is a lovely way of saying that it is a special word that mysql sees to mean something within a query normally. on that note, it really might not be the best idea to use the reserved words as columns in your table - you will have to backtick them in every single instance that you use them. You might want to consider renaming it to something like `toUser` which will probably make the rest of your project easier to SQL out :)

Comment: Note that in this specific case, `TO` _must_ be quoted with backtickts since it is [a reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, I should have said that in the answer. That was was ticked me off on it in the first place. And edited to include the more thorough answer.

Answer (score 2):

You put the `'to'` between single quotes. Column names are not quoted, or between backquotes. Single quotes are for strings. You cannot update a string, hence `SET 'to'='user'` is an error.

```
INSERT INTO rivase_chat_posts 
SET `sender`='$user', `content`='$msg', `time`='$wholetime', `to`='$affectuser'
```

UPDATE: comments say `to` is a reserved word and should always be escaped - using backquotes.

Comment: `TO` is also a reserved word. Must be quoted with backticks.

Answer (score 2):

`To` is a reserved word. Escape it:

```
INSERT INTO rivase_chat_posts 
SET sender='$user', content='$msg', time='$wholetime', `to` ='$affectuser'
```